# jQuery - Wrap div to multiple element

Tags: jquery

Hi
Suppose I have the code below:

```
  <div class="Hello">
    <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Goodbye">
    <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Goodnight">
    <div class="inner">Goodnight</div>
  </div>
```

How can I wrap a div to these 3 div?
The result should be:

```
  <div>
      <div class="Hello">
        <div class="inner">Hello</div>
      </div>
      <div class="Goodbye">
        <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
      </div>
      <div class="Goodnight">
        <div class="inner">Goodnight</div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Update(not work)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>

<div class="Hello">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
</div>
<div class="Goodbye">
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
<div class="Goodnight">
  <div class="inner">Goodnight</div>
</div>

<script>
$("<div>").insertBefore(".Hello").append(".Hello, .Goodbye, .Goodnight");   
</script>
```

Updated 2(work)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>

<div class="Hello">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
</div>
<div class="Goodbye">
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
<div class="Goodnight">
  <div class="inner">Goodnight</div>
</div>

<script>
$("<div>").insertBefore(".Hello").append($('.Hello'), $('.Goodbye'), $('.Goodnight'));  
</script>
```

Updated 3(not work)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>

<div class="Hello">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
</div>
<div class="Goodbye">
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
<div class="Goodnight">
  <div class="inner">Goodnight</div>
</div>

<script>
//$("<div>").insertBefore(".Hello").append($('.Hello'), $('.Goodbye'), $('.Goodnight'));    
$(".Hello, .Goodbye, .Goodnight").wrap('div');
</script>
```

Result:

```
<div class="Hello">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
<div class="Hello">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
</div></div>
<div class="Hello">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
<div class="Hello">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
</div><div class="Goodbye">
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div></div>
<div class="Hello">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
<div class="Hello">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
</div><div class="Goodnight">
  <div class="inner">Goodnight</div>
</div></div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the `.wrap()` method. Just create a new div and `.append()` each element.
E.g:

```
$("<div>")
    .insertBefore(".Hello")
    .append($(".Hello, .Goodbye, .Goodnight"));
```

The divs will be moved inside, not cloned.